# How to add cuda drivers to gcp Ubuntu vm?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, gpu

When I run a pytorch model on a google virtual machine using:

```
model.cuda()
```

I get this error:

```
AssertionError: 
Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you
have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from
http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020-05-01, GCP default machines run 9.12. So it's hard to use the default repository :

```
ppa:graphics-drivers
```

I recommend just downloading the driver yourself and installing it :

```
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/440.82/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run
```

Then run it in sudo mode :

```
 sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run
```

Accept everything and you should be okay to use your GPU